# Initialisation of char array to string value, are the uninitialised indices set to null?

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration

If I have the following:

```
char test[10] = "#";
```

Is `test[1]` through `test[9]` guaranteed to be `\0`? Or is only `test[1]` guaranteed to be `\0`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This definition

```
char test[10] = "#";
```

is equivalent to

```
char test[10] = { '#', '\0' };
```

That is two elements of the array are initialized explicitly by the initializers. All other elements of the array will be zero initialized that is implicitly they will be set tto '\0'

According to the C++ Standard (section 8.5.2 Character arrays)

> 3 If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each
>   element not explicitly initialized shall be **zero-initialized** (8.5).

Comment: Thanks, do you have the line from the specification that states this?